# Flex: Skinning menuBar - is it possible?

Tags: apache-flex

I wish to skin MenuBar, and change it's itemSkin to something else, like different background color for each menu item.

- Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but I wouldn't go down that road. If you want to skin, you're better of with Spark components. You can usually recreate the behavior of mx components quite easily with the existing Spark components (except Tree and ADG)

Comment: good, can you link me then the Spark MenuBar, because i dont see it arround :D Now seriously : what class then i shall use in order to replace MenuBar ?

Comment: It doesn't exist out of the box, but you can create a menu with a ButtonBar or a List for the main menu and a List in a PopUpAnchor for the submenus.

Comment: nah.. this neither will do the work, neither will be even close to the rest of the look and feel :|

Comment: It does the work for me and since they're Spark components, you can give them any look and feel you wish for. (It becomes more complex if you want multi-level menus though, but I consider that a sign of poor UI design anyway)

Comment: could be, could be, but this is not mine design, it's the boss ... :E so i need to fight my way trough it , you know ... "the gods orders" :D

Comment: Well, then you should tell him that either you'll have to (try to) skin mx:MenuBar or you'll have to create your own Spark version of it; both of which will take a up lot of time.

Comment: Nah. I dont wana commit suicide, i am still young ... :D Better wait for another solution. Specifically with MenuBar.

Comment: That's a pretty good argument ;) But be prepared for "Why did it take you so long?" If you don't warn him now, you won't be able to say "I told you so", because you didn't.

Comment: :D better receive a of thoose : "I told you so" :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

the main idea is to create a class overriding MenuBarItem.
Then - about the background - i have create one Image to store the color, and i switched it's position with the label of the menu item.

So far it is sufficiently good solution. :)