# grouped tab navigator as3

Tags: actionscript-3, extend, tabnavigator

hi is it possible to create/ extend from tab navigator or another component to create a tab navigator where tabs are within tabs. I.e grouped. I have been trying to find some info on this but there is very little available. I have attempted to do something as follows but I cannot successfully get it to work. Any expansion or information on this would be great

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940728/how-to-create-and-manage-a-nested-tabbedviewnavigator)?

Comment: no, I have a tab navigator with roughly 20 tabs. what I need is to be able to group them into 4 tabs for example. So each of my 4 tabs will have 5 sub-tabs within them that will be visible only when I click their parent tab. i found something like what im after on google images - thanks

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sub+menu&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=rYXPU6qeD9Oy7Abe6oGADA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=899#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=kXgjjPqBOOJxlM%253A%3BcPrGV_ZpzEaNgM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fi.stack.imgur.com%252FL0pCj.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fstackoverflow.com%252Fquestions%252F10837855%252Fmenu-style-in-wordpress%3B878%3B335

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Flex MenuBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d8e.html) with custom skin for it. Or, maybe it will be easier, you can try to write own component based on Spark [ButtonBar (or TabBar)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-59bf082612135c9e688-8000.html) with [List](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/List.html) as suggested in [Flex: Skinning menuBar - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486158/flex-skinning-menubar-is-it-possible)